How to recursively download path or filenames, without downloading the actual files?
I want to download the filenames or paths of over 1 mil files on a NASA data repository, without actually downloading the files. What is the best way to do this? Does wget supports this functionality?
The repository is:
https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/archive/allData/61/MYD04_L2/

It would help if we knew what format the repository is currently in and a little about your use case and if it's a one-time thing.  If the files are listed on an index page, you could pull that page and process the results offline.  If there are subdirectories that need to be traversed, this could get trickier.  wget probably isn't the best choice.  You probably want some sort of web scraper/crawler, whether it be a standalone tool, a browser extension/dev tools script, or something like Python.

the repository link has been added.

Are you saying that you just need their paths or also trying to download? Reading through the documentation: https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Download-Options Doing a dry run doesn't seem feasible. If you are wanting paths you may want to use powershell to parse through them all and print them out.

This isn't really an answer at the moment. Perhaps you could provide some sample PowerShell code in order to show that could be an answer?

--spider makes wget not actually download the files.
Aim it at a higher directory, use --spider and maybe tweak the recursive limit (and restrict yourself to subdirectories somehow).
It is very easy to make a wget command that rudely grabs too much data.  Do a LOT of dry runs and tests before you run it.
